# Eclipse text editor get caret position

Tags: java, eclipse, text-editor

As one component of a project I have a table with a list of variables from the current class in scope of the eclipse text editor.  I want to be able to double click a position in this table and have the contents printed to the screen for me using a JavaRobot.  Everything is set but of course when I click the table, the text editor caret position disappears as the foreground job is the table.  Is there a way to find out the caret position so then I know where it was and thus print the contents into the desired location?

I have seen it done with textPanes:

```
int currentCaretPosition = textPane.getCaretPosition();
```

[image: Figure 1]

On the left is an example table when I click it the cursor/caret position disappears.

[image: Figure 2]

Need to get the cursor position and save it so I can print to this location using JavaRobot when a user double clicks a column/row.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. Can you post pictures of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Eclipse views are built using SWT, not Swing.  I don't know what JavaRobot is.  Could you provide a link?

Comment: JavaRobot has keyboard emulation built into its API.  Can you get the caret position from SWT ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, using SWT is what I needed :)

Here is the code for future reference:

```
CurrentDisplay display = new CurrentDisplay();
Display previousDisplay =display.getDisplay();
Point caretPoisition = previousDisplay.getCursorLocation();
```